# Script for exporting/importing a Python Virtual Environment (venv) - I'm looking for a way to easily move it to another computer

Tags: python, batch-file, duplicates, copy, environment

Normally when I want to move a Python-project to another computer it's always a bit of a hassle. I thought maybe there was a way to export/import a project with a bat-script (Windows 10), but I suspect it's a bit more tricky.

What I normally do when I want to move a project to another computer is that I first create the requests-file (with pip freeze), then install the Python-version used in my venv globally on the other computer, then I set up my venv (linking to the python-version installed) and lastly installing the modules from the requests-file. Is there some way to do this without actually installing the Python-version used globally, and instead just link to the setup-file instead when creating the venv? Or are there any different alternatives on how to move a project (with a virtual environment) "with the click of a button" to a new computer?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it, just thought I'd share if anyone else is interested. There might be better ways to do this though, so feel free to improve upon my solution :)

**My main project:**

In my main project (which I want to move to another computer) I have created a folder with the Python-installer I've used for my Virtual Environment: `PROJECTFOLDER\Installers\python-3.10.8-amd64.exe`.

I have also created two bat-scripts which is placed in the projectfolder:

- `VENV_1_GenerateRequests.bat` - This script that creates requests.txt (the file which contains all installed modules and their versions)
- `VENV_2_InitializeOnNewComputer.bat` - When the project is copied to a new computer this script will Install the correct Python-version and set up the environment.

**How to copy and initialize the project on another computer:**

- In the main project, run `VENV_1_GenerateRequests.bat` to generate the requests.txt.
- Copy the entire project (*except for the `venv` folder*) to the new computer. This step could be simplified further by creating a bat-script that uses 7zip to zip the project (excluding the venv-folder).
- On the new computer, run `VENV_2_InitializeOnNewComputer.bat` to intialize the project with an identical Virtual Environment as in the sourceproject.

**VENV_1_GenerateRequests.bat**

```
:: GENERATES REQUESTS.TXT
@ECHO OFF
cmd /K "CD /D %~dp0\venv\Scripts & activate & CD /D %~dp0 & pip freeze > requests.txt"
PAUSE
```

**VENV_2_InitializeOnNewComputer.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF

:: Go to the current directory
CD /D %~dp0

:: Install Python
TITLE Installing Python
"Installers\python-3.10.8-amd64.exe" /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 TargetDir="C:\Python310"

:: Create a Virtual Environment (venv) in the current directory
TITLE Creating Virtual Environment (venv)
CD /D %~dp0
"C:\Python310\python.exe" -m venv venv

:: Installing modules from requests.txt
TITLE "Installing modules from requests.txt"
cmd /K "CD /D %~dp0\venv\Scripts & activate & CD /D %~dp0 & pip install -r requests.txt & TITLE Finished intializing Virtual Environment"
```